# Change order of tabs in TabLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, tab-ordering

I have a typical TabLayout with a ViewPager attached to it so I can scroll through it by both swiping views and clicking on the tabs (just like presented [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view) and cannot find a way of allowing users to reorder those tabs (and the corresponding pages)

I would like it to work like this: the user long presses one tab and drags it to the left and right, switching position with the others, just like you do with `ItemTouchHelper` and `RecycleView`.

Problem is, I don't find anything like `ItemTouchHelper` for `TabLayout`, if it even exists.

Answer (score -1):

**Use LTR RTL To change tablayout Order Position inside onTabSelected.**

```
        subTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
        override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
          
            if(tab.position == 0)
                subTabLayout.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR)
            else
                subTabLayout.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL)
            subViewPager.currentItem = tab.position

        }

        override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

        }

        override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

        }
    })
```

[image][image]